# Why can't my AppleScript get my Xcode project?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, applescript, applescript-objc

I want to run an iPhone project in the iOS Simulator using AppleScript, so I wrote this code:

```
tell application "Xcode"
    open "IAPPS:Xcode 4:EightQueens:EightQueens.xcodeproj"
    tell project "EightQueens.xcodeproj"
        clean
        build
        try
            debug
        end try
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

But it is giving me this error:

```
Xcode got an error: Can’t get project "EightQueens.xcodeproj".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It is because your project isn't named *"EightQueens.**xcodeproj**"*.

Instead of
`tell project "EightQueens.xcodeproj"`
do:
`tell project "EightQueens"`

Comment: Its again the same error  Xcode got an error: Can’t get project "EightQueens.xcodeproj".

Comment: You need to isolate more your problem. Is the error appearing on the line "open …" or the line "tell project …" ?